# ReadyRoll server details for VSTS Build phase

Tags: azure-sql-database, readyroll

I am trying to implement the CI/CD for ReadyRoll. For the release portion I am using an Azure SQL Server so I have specified the server name, db name and cred there. However, I am not sure what details do I give for the build component when creating the shadow db. I thought they were the same but then I get an error saying that its trying to create a db in my azure sql server and it fails because there's already a db with that name there. This led me to think I am supplying the wrong values but I am not sure what is that I am to supply.

Comment: Try asking your question on Redgate forum for this product. https://forum.red-gate.com/categories/readyroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ReadyRoll maintains two databases:
>
> •Target database
>
> This is the development database or sandbox that you use for
>   debugging and to edit schema objects (e.g. using SSMS). When you
>   deploy, ReadyRoll executes your migration scripts against this
>   database to upgrade it. You shouldn't drop the target database from
>   your SQL Server instance.
>
> •Shadow database
>
> This is an exact copy of your database schema created automatically
>   from your project scripts (001.sql, 002.sql, 003.sql, etc). It's
>   created every time you use the ReadyRoll DbSync tool to view pending
>   changes or import. The shadow database is used by the SQL Compare
>   engine (that powers ReadyRoll) as the base from which to generate a
>   new migration script. It is safe to drop the database at any time.

More information: [Target and shadow databases](https://documentation.red-gate.com/display/RR1/Target+and+shadow+databases?_ga=2.109683205.1861868405.1501207010-266735598.1500344840)

You can specify these arguments for shadow database: ShadowServer, ShadowUserName, ShadowPassword, ShadowDatabase. (You also can just specify target database)

More information: [Shadow database](https://documentation.red-gate.com/display/RR1/Continuous+Integration+and+Deployment#ContinuousIntegrationandDeployment-Shadowdatabase)

The sample for MSBuild Arguments of Visual Studio Build task:

```
/p:TargetServer=XXX.database.windows.net  /p:TargetUsername=XXX /p:TargetPassword=XXX /p:ShadowServer=XXX /p:TargetDatabase=XXX /p:GenerateSqlPackage=True /p:SkipDriftAnalysis=True /p:ShadowUserName=XXX /p:ShadowPassword=XXX /p:DBDeployOnBuild=True
```